# How to create an external Hive table with column typed Timestamp

Tags: timestamp, hive, hiveql

I want to create an external Hive table from a text file containing epoch in HDFS. Let's say the file is located at the `/user/me/test.txt`. Here's the file content:

```
1354183921
1354183922
```

I have Hive 0.8.1 installed and should be able to use type Timestamp, so I created the table:

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1 (epoch Timestamp)
      LOCATION '/user/me';
```

Then I queried the table:

```
SELECT * FROM test1;
```

and got the following exception:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Have I missed anything when creating the external table? I'm confused because Hive (since 0.8) supports Timestamp in the format of Unix epoch in second: https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-types.html#LanguageManualTypes-Timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Timestamp string must be in the format specified in the error message and link, yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]. To use data that contains epoch, you would have to define as a BIGINT and then use the built-in UDF, from_unixtime() to convert to a string representing the date. Then you could use the other [built-in UDF date functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) to manipulate this date.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Hope Hive can update their documentation to make this point clear in the future.