# Getting error while retrieving columns on HIVE "TIMESTAMP" column

Tags: sql, apache, hive, bigdata

In Hive, I am trying create table on log file, I have data in the following format.

- 1000000000012311 1373346000 21.4 XX
- 1000000020017331 1358488800 16.9 YY

In this second field is Unix timestamp. I am writing following HIVE QUERY:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE log(user STRING, tdate TIMESTAMP, spend DOUBLE, state STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' LOCATION '/user/XXX/YYY/ZZZ';
```

Table is created. but when I am trying to get the data from table `Select * form log limit 10';`
I am getting following error.

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating tdate

I have checked the HIVE manual and also google it, but didn't get any solution.

Comment: what version of Hive are you using , I think Hive v0.8.0 added types for timestamps so ...

Answer (score 2):

For epoch, you can define as  BIGINT and then use the built-in UDF, from_unixtime() to convert to a string representing the date. Some thing like "select from_unixtime(tdate) from log "

A similar post at this link : **[How to create an external Hive table with column typed Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625400/how-to-create-an-external-hive-table-with-column-typed-timestamp)**

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports the datatype timestamp but when used with JDBC cannot accept Timestamp as a datatype. But this was a problem in earlier versions. From Hive version 0.8.0, this problem is fixed. You can checkout this JIRA ticket raised.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-2957