# How to convert date format 'DDMONYYYY:HH....' style date in Hive

Tags: date, hadoop, hive

I am inserting dates that look like:

`'19APR2014:08:42:32.123456'`

I am interpreting their format as

`'DDMONYYYY:HH24:MI:SS.FFFFFF'`

Though I have not seen any times after **12:59:59** I am assuming a 24-hour clock. Hive does not seem to understand what I want to do:

`HiveException: Error evaluating unix_timestamp(date_string,'DDMONYYYY:HH24:MI:SS.FFFFFF')`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what might be wrong with my format string?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625400/how-to-create-an-external-hive-table-with-column-typed-timestamp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `ddMMMyyyy:HH:mm:ss.SSS`? According to Hive [manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) a pattern string in function `unix_timestamp(string date, string pattern)` should comply to Java's SimpleDateFormat(see [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) and [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).